# GeoCoordinates Format

Tags: sql, geolocation, coordinates

I am trying to read data from existing database and one column has geo coordinates but this coordinates are not in Latitude and Longitude format.

The existing format is the following :

> 84060571645158400

how I can get Latitude and Longitude from this number ?

Comment: And what values would you want from this example?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to get  Latitude and Longitude

Comment: @AliMardini: And which lat long pair corresponds to 84060571645158400?

Comment: @stickybit this is what I don't understand how its stored in database, I am trying to get lat long from this number

Comment: @AliMardini: Yes I understand that you want to get lat and lon. But I asked what lat/lon corresponds to 84060571645158400? Or do you have another example of such a number with a know lat/lon?

Comment: @stickybit unfortunately I don't know the actual lat/lon that corresponds to this number and I don't have any other example

Comment: @AliMardini: Hmm, that makes that pretty much unsolvable. How are going to check if an assumption is right or wrong?

Comment: At least, what is the geo region the point is supposed to belong to?

Comment: @Serg The geo region is Persian gulf

Comment: @stickybit This is why its a problem for me

Comment: Then one possible decoding is 8.4060571 N , 64.5158400 E somewhere in Arabian sea.

Comment: @Serg ok, so how do you decoded ?

Comment: This string is 17 digits long, odd number. My guess is a leading zero is omitted, that is 2+7 digits lon and lat each. According to the supposed region first is lat, second is lon.